# Count number of AsyncTask that is running and show to progressBar

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have mai Asynctask that run a taks.in onPostExecute method i have executed another Asynctask That run almost 50 time.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressBar = new ProgressBar(MainActivity.this,null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
    progressDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,
....


protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
...
for (Get_NIdCadastre_NIdVisitContractCadastre get : a) {
get_List_Visit visit = new get_List_Visit(get.getNIdCadastre(), get.getNIdVisitContractCadastre());
visit.executeOnExecutor((AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR), NIdCadastre, NIdVisitContractCadastre);
...
if (progressDialog.isShowing()){
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Now, in get_List_Visit task at **doInBackground** method  by **publishProgress** I want show number of task is running or that task was finished its task :

```
private class get_List_Visit extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

 @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    //?
```

that is mean every time that is new task executing I want to show, what number of task is execute!!!

I know about `AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING` but how could I use this into my situation?
sorry for my english!!!

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

From the Android Docs:

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds
>   at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of
>   time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by
>   the java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor
>   and FutureTask.
>
> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

AsyncTask is not the right tool for the job, from the sounds of what you're saying. I recommend you look into [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).

If you insist on the AsyncTask approach, you can implement it using the Delegate/Protocol design pattern. Then in the postback in your activity, you can update the progress bar accordingly.

Comment: What? Volley is for networking, but there is nothing in the question saying that he is doing network stuff in the AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

little suggestion from me is that ,take one `Static` `int variable` and in start of first `asyncTask` increment it and at the `result` decrements it .And finally show current result of `variable` in your `ProgressBar`.